# How to reorder indexed rows based on a list in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
company  Amazon  Apple  Yahoo
name
A             0    130      0
C           173      0      0
Z             0      0    150
```

It was created using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'Z','C'],
                   'company' : ['Apple', 'Yahoo','Amazon'],
                   'height' : [130, 150,173]})

df = df.pivot(index="name", columns="company", values="height").fillna(0)
```

What I want to do is to sort the row (with index `name`) according to a predefined list:

```
["Z", "C", "A"]`
```

Resulting in this :

```
company  Amazon  Apple  Yahoo
name
Z             0      0    150
C           173      0      0
A             0    130      0
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You could set index on predefined order using `reindex` like

```
In [14]: df.reindex(["Z", "C", "A"])
Out[14]:
company  Amazon  Apple  Yahoo
Z             0      0    150
C           173      0      0
A             0    130      0
```

However, if it's alphabetical order, you could use `sort_index(ascending=False)`

```
In [12]: df.sort_index(ascending=False)
Out[12]:
company  Amazon  Apple  Yahoo
name
Z             0      0    150
C           173      0      0
A             0    130      0
```

Like pointed below, you need to assign it to some variable

```
In [13]: df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Note that this does not modify the array, you have to assign it to something.

Comment: Also note that if you happened to have a multi-index, you would need to use additional parameters in your reindex call, e.g. `df.reindex(axis='index', level=0, labels=yourlabels_list)` or your labels would need to match your multi-index.

Comment: When I execute this code, all my values are changed to "nan". Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

Comment: @ Robvh , this occurs when the values of the list passed to df.reindex() (```["Z", "C", "A"]``` in the example) are not indices of ```df``` so it makes new rows with the new indices that contain no data.

Answer (score 12):

We could also use `loc`:

```
lst = ["Z", "C", "A"]
df = df.loc[lst]
```

Output:

```
company  Amazon  Apple  Yahoo
name                         
Z             0      0    150
C           173      0      0
A             0    130      0
```

Note that if there are values in `lst` that does not exist in `df.index` (e.g. if `lst=['Z','C','A','D']`), then `loc` throws a KeyError (whereas `reindex` creates a new row `'D'` full of NaNs).

---

#### MultiIndex

If `df` is MultiIndex, such as:

```
           C3
C1 C2        
2  evelen   0
   ten      1
   twelve   2
1  evelen   3
   ten      4
   twelve   5
```

and if you want to sort the second level by `ten`,`eleven` and`twelve`, then using `loc`:

```
out = df.loc[:, ['ten','evelen', 'twelve'],:]
```

Output:

```
           C3
C1 C2        
2  evelen   0
   ten      1
   twelve   2
1  evelen   3
   ten      4
   twelve   5
```

and for both levels:

```
out = df.loc[[1,2], ['ten','evelen','twelve'], :]
```

Output:

```
           C3
C1 C2        
1  ten      4
   evelen   3
   twelve   5
2  ten      1
   evelen   0
   twelve   2
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, specially if you want to sort by multiples values, the best solution is:

```py
df = df.set_index("C1")
df = df.sort_values(["C1", "C2"])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```