# how to reorder pandas data frame rows based on external index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to reorder the rows in a dataframe based on an external mapping. So for example if the list is (2,1,3) I want to move the first item in the old df to the second item in the new df. I thought my question was the same as this: [How to reorder indexed rows based on a list in Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009948/how-to-reorder-indexed-rows-based-on-a-list-in-pandas-data-frame) but that solution is not working. Here's what I've tried:

```
a = list(sampleinfo.filename)
b = list(exprs.columns)
matchIndex2 = [a.index(x) for x in b]

(1)
    sampleinfo2 = sampleinfo[matchIndex2,]

(2) 
    sampleinfo2 = sampleinfo
    sampleinfo2.reindex(matchIndex2)
```

Neither solution errors out, but the order doesn't change - it's like I haven't done anything.

I am trying to make sure that the columns in exprs and the filename values of the rows in sampleinfo are in the same order. In the solution I see online I see I can sort the columns of exprs instead:

```
a = list(sampleinfo.filename)
b = list(exprs.columns)
matchIndex = [b.index(x) for x in a]
exprs = exprs[matchIndex]
```

But I'd like to be able to sort by row. How can I do this?

The dataframes I am working with are too large to paste, but here's the general scenario:

```
exprs: 
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 
1  2  2  2  1
4  3  2  1  1

sampleinfo:
filename   otherstuff
a1          fwsegs
a5          gsgers
a3          grsgs
a2          gsgs
a4          sgs
```

Comment: Can you post sample df's and desired output, you can use another series and call `reindex_like` or add a temp column with the order you want order by that column and drop the temp column

Comment: @EdChum I will try creating a temp column with the new ordering, but how to order by a non-indexed column? I realized I could change the column that was the index to reindex, but this seems clumsy and prone to error even if it does work. Seems like reindex_like also works with the index column only?

Comment: After adding a temp column you call `df.sort(temp_col_name)`, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to re-order rows using an external list that is tied to a particular column in the data frame:

```
def reorder(A, column, values):
    """Re-order data frame based on a column (given in the parameter
       column, which must have unique values)"""
    if set(A[column]) != set(values):
        raise Exception("ERROR missing values for re-ordering")
    at_position = {}
    index = 0;
    for v in A[column]:
        at_position[v] = index
        index += 1
    re_position = [ at_position[v] for v in values ]
    return A.iloc[ re_position ];
```