# How can I sort a dataframe on some column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({
    "item_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "customer": ["CG", "CGD", "CC", "CZ", "JD", "KD", "MM", "MK", "JJ"],
    "costs": [150, 12, 78, 56, 5, 6, 4, 68, 69],
    "games": [["Minecraft", "Uno"], ["WOW", "Minecraft"], ["WOW", "Minecraft"], ["WOW", "Minecraft", "The last of us"], ["Monopoly"], ["Monopoly", "Uno"], ["WOW", "Monopoly"], ["Uno", "SkipBo"], ["Schach", "Uno"]], 
    "date": ["2022-01-18", "2022-03-12", "2022-02-26", "2021-11-12", "2021-10-09", "2021-11-26", "2021-10-18", "2021-12-22", "2021-09-06"]
})

DF["games"] = [i[-1:] for i in DF["games"]]
DF["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.day
DF["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.month
DF["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.year
DF #(look at pic_1)

newDF_month = DF.drop(columns=["item_id", "customer", "games", "date", "Day", "Year"])
newDF_month.groupby(["Month"]).sum()
```

But this presents the data ordered by month using the ordering (1,2,3,9,10,11,12):

```
month | costs
-------------
   1  | 150
   2  |  78
   3  |  12
   9  |  69
  10  |   9
  11  |  62
  12  |  68
```

but I would like to have the ordering be (9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3) instead:

```
month | costs
-------------
   9  |  69
  10  |   9
  11  |  62
  12  |  68
   1  | 150
   2  |  78
   3  |  12
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just typing out the sequence might be more readable than @mozway's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009948/how-to-reorder-indexed-rows-based-on-a-list-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: @Joooeey of course of you know the exact indices `reindex([9,10,11,12,1,2,3])` is more explicit. But if you have missing values, you'll end up with NaNs ;)

Comment: Can you use year for sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on its shifted value modulo 12:

```
(newDF_month
 .groupby(["Month"]).sum()
 .sort_index(key=lambda i: (i-9)%12)
)
```

Output:

```
       costs
Month       
9         69
10         9
11        62
12        68
1        150
2         78
3         12
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
new = newDF_month.groupby(["Month"]).sum()
m = new.index >= 9
pd.concat([new.loc[m, :], new.loc[~m, :]])
```

Output:

```
       costs
Month       
9         69
10         9
11        62
12        68
1        150
2         78
3         12
```